# Bunch of errors that aren't valid, probably because of formatting but I can't crack it

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, record

```
public class TicketTest
{
    int serial;
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int total_sales = 0;
                new WebTicket(10);
                new WebTicket(5);
                new CounterTicket();
                new DiscountTicket(5, "Student");
                new DiscountTicket(10, "Senior");
        
        
    }
}

class Ticket(int days, String type) {
    public static int COUNTER_TICKET_PRICE = 50; 
    public static int WEB_TICKET_PRICE = 30; 
    public static int WEB_TICKET_LT_WEEK_PRICE = 40; 
    public static double DISCOUNT = 0.5;
    int serial;
    int price;
}
class WebTicket extends Ticket {
    if (days>7) {
        price = 40;
    }else {
        price = 30;
    }
    System.out.println("Ticket: [serial= "+serial+" Price: "+price+"]");
    serial += 1;
}
class CounterTicket extends Ticket {
    price = 50;
    System.out.println("Ticket: [serial= "+serial+" Price: "+price+"]");
    serial += 1;
}
class DiscountTicket extends Ticket {
    if (days>7) {
        price = 20;
    }else {
        price = 15;
    }
    System.out.println("Ticket: [serial= "+serial+" Price: "+price+" Type: "+type+"]");
    serial += 1;
}
```

I'm trying to make a program that prints ticket info when those classes in the main method are called, but the "class" in class Ticket is getting and error saying a record is expected and the new __Ticket things in the main method aren't being recognized.

Console looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression
    tickets cannot be resolved to a variable
    tickets cannot be resolved to a variable
    tickets cannot be resolved to a variable
    tickets cannot be resolved to a variable

    at test.TicketTest.main(TicketTest.java:12)
```

I tried to delete/add curly braces where I could but to no avail. It's probably a typo or something that I can't find.

Comment: Your various classes need to be in separate `.java` files...

Comment: @TrippKinetics: that's only true for public top-level classes. All classes other than `TicketTest` have default access (i.e. they are not public). While this is unusual and probably not a good idea, it is acceptable for them to all be in one file.

Comment: @OP: your code is ... wrong on so many levels. You have code inside of classes that's not inside a method or constructor, that won't work. And you seem to *try* to define a record `Ticket` but use `class` instead of `record`. Are you following any kind of tutorial, because this seems like a weird mix of mistakes to make ... Also: what IDE are you using? You seem to be trying to *run* code that doesn't compile. That's ... a bad idea and few IDEs support that. So look at the *compile errors* before you try to run anything.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That's really weird.  I think that would definitely not be best practice...

Comment: @TrippKinetics: oh, it's definitely not best practice, no. But it's also not the cause of the problems here. There's not much use harking on best practice when OP has trouble getting something to run in the first place ...

Comment: I think the OP is confusing functions with classes.

Comment: Or the OP is copying from some other language.  Putting raw code directly in the class like this I think is Python-ish, but it's literally been over 15 years since I've seriously looked at any Python.

Comment: Don't try to run code that compiles with errors.

Comment: `class Ticket(int days, String type) {` that is invalid syntax. `class WebTicket extends Ticket { if (days>7) {` is also invalid syntax. Instead of telling us the compiler is wrong (it isn't), read the messages it is telling you.

Comment: Everything I see is convincing me more and more that  the OP is defining classes where they *mean* to be defining functions.

Comment: I think it might be of benefit to not be using an IDE here.  If you are just using a text editor with `javac`, then you wouldn't be getting a `.class` file in the first place, because the compile would error out.

Answer (score 0):

@TrippKinetics Yeah, that was my problem. I had to make functions inside of the classes to make constructors to call, and I was trying to pass params in classes. Thanks!